# Svelthree - How do I add edges and lines to a scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js, svelte

I am trying to add edges to a an object using Svelthree.

I know how to add a geometry to a scene using mesh but how do I add lines at the edges of the geometry?

This is from the official REPL (https://svelthree.dev/examples#hello-cube):

```
 <Scene {sti} let:scene id="scene1" props={{ background: 0xedf2f7 }}>

<PerspectiveCamera {scene} id="cam1" pos={[0, 0, 3]} lookAt={[0, 0, 0]} />
<AmbientLight {scene} intensity={1.25} />
<DirectionalLight {scene} pos={[3, 3, 3]} />

<Mesh
  {scene}
  geometry={cubeGeometry}
  material={cubeMaterial}
  mat={{ roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5, color: 0xff3e00 }}
  pos={[0, 0, 0]}
  rot={[0.5, 0.6, 0]}
  scale={[1, 1, 1]} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered your question on [GitHub](https://github.com/vatro/svelthree/issues/34#issuecomment-735294873)

*Short version*:

Currently there is no 'Line'-component available, but with Mesh and Scene instances available, you can basically do anything you want vanilla three style.

[See REPL (based on svelthree 'Hello cube')](https://svelthree.dev/repl/b487071cb04f4065bd62de9a6f5b838a?version=3.30.0)